# Replace word with image in javascript file

Tags: javascript

I need to modify a javascript file which I'm currently using to display images (it's a standard lightbox JS). This is the part of the script that I need to modify:

```
settings : function() {
    var t = this, s = shutterSettings;

    t.imageCount = s.imageCount || 0;
    t.msgLoading = s.msgLoading || 'L O A D I N G';
    t.msgClose = s.msgClose || 'Click to Close';
},
```

Basically I need to replace the word 'LOADING' in the script with a loading-bar gif. Could someone point me in the right direction (link to a tutorial, manual etc.) on how to do this? I tried to replace the word with an `<img>` or `<div>` tag but that didn't worked.

Comment: You can't replace a word with a gif. You can replace some markup with other markup that displays a gif, but `t` doesn't look like an element to me.

Comment: This change must be done inside the lightbox plugin. Can you give us a link to it?

Comment: This is the link: http://redflexmedia.com/portfolio/portfolio/photography Enter any gallery, click on an image and while the image is loading you will see that a big red "Loading" will appear briefly. I need to replace that word with an image.

Comment: Check my answer, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this replacement **inside** the lightbox plugin, not in its settings.

The `msgLoading` is very likely considered to be given as a string and the string received is set as the text of a `div`, `p` or `span` element.

If you post a link to the lighbox plugin's js file or tell us the name of the plugin or the site where you downloaded it, maybe I can give you a more precise answer. The fact that it's a standard lightbox JS is not exactly helpful

[edit]So it seems you are using [Shutter Reloaded for NextGEN Gallery](http://www.laptoptips.ca/javascripts/shutter-reloaded/)
If you look inside the plugin's js file ([here](http://redflexmedia.com/portfolio/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.js?ver=1.3.3), in your case), you will see that the `innerHTML` is set, so using an `img` should work.

```
loading : function() {
        var t = this, S, WB, W;
        if ( (W = t.I('shWrap')) && W.style.visibility == 'visible' ) return;
        if ( ! (S = t.I('shShutter')) ) return;
        if ( t.I('shWaitBar') ) return;
        WB = document.createElement('div');
        WB.setAttribute('id','shWaitBar');
        WB.style.top = t.Top + 'px';
        WB.style.marginTop =(t.pgHeight/2) + 'px'
        WB.innerHTML = t.msgLoading;
        S.appendChild(WB);
    },
```

Try with these settings:

```
var shutterSettings = {"msgLoading":"<img src=\"http://redflexmedia.com/loading.gif\">","msgClose":"Click to Close","imageCount":"1"};
```

[edit]The code above must be placed inside the HTML file, in the `head` section, **NOT** the plugin.

That means you must replace this part

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var shutterSettings = {"msgLoading":"<img src=\"http://redflexmedia.com/loading.gif\">","msgClose":"Click to Close","imageCount":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

with

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var shutterSettings = {"msgLoading":"L O A D I N G","msgClose":"Click to Close","imageCount":"1"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I tried but now I see the word 'undefined' instead of the image.

Comment: Did you put the settings in the html file? You should use it there, not inside the plugin. Looking at the source here http://redflexmedia.com/portfolio/portfolio/photography I can still see the old `var settings`

Comment: @GeorgeGrigorita I took a look at your site and caught you in the act, you were editing in the wrong place. Check the edit on my post, please

Comment: OK, now I understand what should go where, but I need to figure out what is the right file to edit. The /photography/ HTML file is generated by wordpress + nextgen plugin + shutter reloaded. I think it should be ngg-gallery.php but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: If you want to edit the plugin directly, you can do it like this: `t.msgLoading = '<img src="http://example.com/loading.gif">';` I believe you were not escaping the quotes the first time you edited the plugin and that's why I think it didn't work

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now it works and the file which outputs the `shutterSettings` in the final HTML is `nggallery.php` (for future references - if anyone has this problem). Thanks for your help, I really appreciated it!

Answer (score 1):

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/ see if the 3rd point helps ...

> If you would like to show the user a 'loading' graphic, like the
> animated progress bar in the examples above, specify its location at
> the top of the lightbox.js file:
>
> `var loadingImage = 'loading.gif';`

Comment: @George Grigorita can you plz direct us to the lightbox.js file you are using...it will help us to dig in more..

Comment: Thanks both for helping, I'm using Shutter Reloaded for NextGEN Gallery: http://redflexmedia.com/portfolio/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/shutter/shutter-reloaded.js?ver=1.3.3